# ElasticSearch data visualization of states monitored of a device with a printer

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i'm monitoring some kiosks that have a printer, the recolectated data say me that have 16 posibles states of the printer (that's the info that `WMI` say me), i need to make a dashboard  whit the last state (if is a problem like `"no paper"` the menssage need to be llamative, be red or something like that, but is some like `"no error"`, the menssage need to be green), thats a exple `JSON` data that i send to `ElasticSearch`

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2019-01-22T17:12:18.431798-0500",
  "beat": {
    "hostname": "PC-TEST",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "PC-TEST"
  },
  "PrinterDevice": {
    "DeviceName": "Impresora-Test",
    "ErrorState": {
      "code": 2,
      "message": "No Error"
    }
  }
}
```

that's another example

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2019-01-22T17:15:18.431798-0500",
  "beat": {
    "hostname": "PC-TEST",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "PC-TEST"
  },
  "PrinterDevice": {
    "DeviceName": "Impresora-Test",
    "ErrorState": {
      "code": 4,
      "message": "No Paper"
    }
  }
}
```

thanks for all

Comment: What tool are you using in order to visualize the results? Is it a custom application or kibana? Are you going to use your own custom query or based on existing visualizations?

Comment: i try with canvas, and kibana visualizations, but the tool it's not important, if you know a alternative o a way to do, the tool its no problem

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the latest state, you can run a simple query, which sorts based on timestamp desc, asking only for one doc, and you'll get the last state:

```
{
  "size" : 1,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
        "must" : [
            "exists" : { "field" : "PrinterDevice.ErrorState.message" }
        ]
    }
  },
  "sort" : [
    {"@timestamp" : {"order" : "desc"}}
  ]
}
```

In case you have multiple devices and you want to run one query to get the last state of all the devices then you can add some aggregations:

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
        "must" : [
            "exists" : { "field" : "PrinterDevice.ErrorState.message" }
        ]
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "state_per_device" : {
        "terms" : { 
            "field" : "PrinterDevice.DeviceName" 
        },
        "aggs" : {
            "latest_state" : {
                "top_hits": {
                    "sort": [
                        {
                            "@timestamp": {
                                "order": "desc"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "_source": {
                        "includes": [ "PrinterDevice.ErrorState.message" ]
                    },
                    "size" : 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This will get you the latest status for each device from elasticsearch. Regarding how to visualize these responses, you can use canvas or any other tool.

Comment: Tanks, but the problem its i don't know how to visualize states, in a llamative style, for example the message say "no toner" i need that the message be red

Comment: Sounds like you either have to write the UI yourself, use canvas, or use Vue.